# pager function not work well while multi grid in one page

Tags: jqgrid, pager

Thank you about open source the jqgrid.

I got a pager problem about multi grid in one page.
There are first grid (eg. contactGrid) and the rest grids(eg. orderGrid) in one page, and contactGrid on top, the rest listed on bottom.
The function of contactGrid is great, but the pager function of rest grids are not work well.

1. Some times after the page initialized, some of the rest grids did
   not show the data requested from server.
2. It do show nothing while I
   click next page, last page, or change the page size on each of the
   rest grids.

I check the network on firefox, it showed the request url like this:

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/hx-customer/saleProblem/bizsaleproblem/list?delFlag=0&customerId=632&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&_=1524161697902

And after the page and all grids initialized, the `console.dir(ts.p.postData)` I added in jqgrid source showed like this:
[after the page and all grids initialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmdxn.png)

I'm using the last version of v5.3.1, jquery version is v2.2.4.

Here are my source code:

```js
var custId,_userName,_contacts,_email,$contactsGrid,$followGrid,$orderGrid,$saleGrid, v, commonParam = '';
$(function () {

    vm.loadDict();

    handleParam();

    custId = localStorage.getItem("addCust#custId");
    if (custId) {
        localStorage.removeItem("addCust#custId");
        commonParam = '&customerId='+custId;
        vm.getInfo(custId);
    } else {
        findUser();
    }

    $("#contactsGrid").jqGrid({
        url: baseURL + 'contact/bizcustomercontact/list?delFlag=0'+commonParam,
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: [
            {label: 'id', name: 'customerContactId', index: 'customer_contact_id', key: true, hidden: true },
            {label: '序号', name: 'customerId', index: 'customer_id', hidden: true},
            {label: '联系人', name: 'contacts', index: 'contacts', width: 80},
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        height: 200,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [2,10, 30, 50],
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 25,
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: true,
        pager: "#contactsGridPager",
        jsonReader: {
            root: "contactPage.list",
            page: "contactPage.currPage",
            total: "contactPage.totalPage",
            records: "contactPage.totalCount"
        },
        prmNames: {
            page: "page",
            rows: "limit",
            order: "order"
        },
        beforeRequest: function () {
            console.dir('contact request', $("#contactsGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData'));
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
            //隐藏grid底部滚动条
            $("#contactsGrid").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").css({"overflow-x": "hidden"});
        }
    });

    $("#followGrid").jqGrid({
        url: baseURL + 'follow/bizfollow/list?delFlag=0'+commonParam,
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: [
            {label: 'id', name: 'followId', index: 'follow_id', width: 50, key: true, hidden: true },
            {label: '序号', name: 'customerId', index: 'customer_id', width: 80, hidden: true},
            {label: '邮件日期', name: 'mailDate', index: 'mail_date', width: 80},
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        height: 200,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [2,10, 30, 50],
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 25,
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: true,
        pager: "#followGridPager",
        jsonReader: {
            root: "followPage.list",
            page: "followPage.currPage",
            total: "followPage.totalPage",
            records: "followPage.totalCount"
        },
        prmNames: {
            page: "page",
            rows: "limit",
            order: "order"
        },
        beforeRequest: function () {
            console.dir('follow request', $("#followGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData'));
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
            //隐藏grid底部滚动条
            $("#followGrid").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").css({"overflow-x": "hidden"});
        }
    });

    $("#orderGrid").jqGrid({
        url: baseURL + 'order/bizorder/list?delFlag=0'+commonParam,
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: [
            {label: 'orderId', name: 'orderId', index: 'order_id', width: 50, key: true, hidden: true },
            {label: '订单日期', name: 'orderDate', index: 'order_date', width: 80},
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        height: 200,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [2,10, 30, 50],
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 25,
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: true,
        pager: "#orderGridPager",
        jsonReader: {
            root: "orderPage.list",
            page: "orderPage.currPage",
            total: "orderPage.totalPage",
            records: "orderPage.totalCount"
        },
        prmNames: {
            page: "page",
            rows: "limit",
            order: "order"
        },
        beforeRequest: function () {
            console.dir('order request', $("#orderGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData'));
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
            //隐藏grid底部滚动条
            $("#orderGrid").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").css({"overflow-x": "hidden"});
        }

    });

    $("#saleGrid").jqGrid({
        url: baseURL + 'saleProblem/bizsaleproblem/list?delFlag=0'+commonParam,
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: [
            {label: 'id', name: 'saleProblemId', index: 'sale_problem_id', width: 50, key: true, hidden: true },
            {label: '反馈日期', name: 'feedbackDate', index: 'feedback_date', width: 80},
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        height: 200,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [2,10, 30, 50],
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 25,
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: true,
        pager: "#saleGridPager",
        jsonReader: {
            root: "salePage.list",
            page: "salePage.currPage",
            total: "salePage.totalPage",
            records: "salePage.totalCount"
        },
        prmNames: {
            page: "page",
            rows: "limit",
            order: "order"
        },
        beforeRequest: function () {
            console.dir('sale request', $("#saleGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData'));
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
            //隐藏grid底部滚动条
            $("#saleGrid").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").css({"overflow-x": "hidden"});
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>客户清单表</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../plugins/jqgrid/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/customer.css">
    <script src="../../libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../../plugins/layer/layer.js"></script>
    <script src="../../libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../libs/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../plugins/jqgrid/grid.locale-cn.js"></script>
    <script src="../../plugins/jqgrid/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/common.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="rrapp" v-cloak>
        <div v-show="showDivTitles" class="panel-heading item-title">客户档案-联系人
            <div class="model-toggle" @click="modelSwitch('showDivContacts')">
                <i class="fa " :class="{ 'fa-caret-square-o-up': showDivContacts, 'fa-caret-square-o-down': !showDivContacts }" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-show="showDivContacts" id="contactsDiv">
            <div v-show="showContacts">
                <table id="contactsGrid"></table>
                <div id="contactsGridPager"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div v-show="showDivTitles" class="panel-heading item-title">客户档案-跟进记录
            <div class="model-toggle" @click="modelSwitch('showDivFollow')">
                <i class="fa " :class="{ 'fa-caret-square-o-up': showDivFollow, 'fa-caret-square-o-down': !showDivFollow }" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
         </div>
        <div v-show="showDivFollow" id="followDiv">
            <div v-show="showFollow">
                <table id="followGrid"></table>
                <div id="followGridPager"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div v-show="showDivTitles" class="panel-heading item-title">客户档案-订单交易
            <div class="model-toggle" @click="modelSwitch('showDivOrder')">
                <i class="fa " :class="{ 'fa-caret-square-o-up': showDivOrder, 'fa-caret-square-o-down': !showDivOrder }" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-show="showDivOrder" id="orderDiv">
            <div v-show="showOrder">
                <table id="orderGrid"></table>
                <div id="orderGridPager"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div v-show="showDivTitles" class="panel-heading item-title">客户档案-售后记录
            <div class="model-toggle" @click="modelSwitch('showDivSale')">
                <i class="fa " :class="{ 'fa-caret-square-o-up': showDivSale, 'fa-caret-square-o-down': !showDivSale }" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-show="showDivSale" id="saleDiv">
            <div v-show="showSale">
                <table id="saleGrid"></table>
                <div id="saleGridPager"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-show="showDivTitles" class="row">
            <div class="common-btn-ground">
                <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-info common-btn" @click="save">保存</button>-->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info common-btn" @click="back"><!-- onclick="history.go(-1)" -->
                    <i class="fa fa-rotate-left"></i>&nbsp返回</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../../js/modules/customer/addCustFile.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking, but it seems that your issue most likely stems from the server request not being populated correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not good at write English. Like the logs shows in 'after the page and all grids initialized' I posted, when I use the pager function, the 'ts.p.postData' were already not a object, but a array.

Comment: Comment again, when I use the pager function, the 'ts.p.postData' in jqgrid function populate were already not a object, but a array. Then jquery ajax handled incrrect request data(lots of undefinded parameters in request url) from 'ts.p.postData'.